# How to automatically copy all events from one calendar to another with GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

It appears I'm missing something fairly obvious in trying to automatically copy all events from one google calendar to another. Others don't want access to the source calendar, so it goes.

Below what doesn't work, as a kick-off.

```
function copyAppointments() {
  var sourceCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("exampleSource@group.calendar.google.com");
  var targetCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("targetExample@group.calendar.google.com");
  var events = sourceCalendar.getEvents();

  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    var event = events[i];
    if (event > -1) {
      targetCalendar.createEvent();
    }
  }
}
```

How would you do this?

Comment: please read the documentation : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar

Comment: There is no method `Calendar.getEvents()` with no parameters and there is no `Calendar.createEvent()` method with no parameters. But you probably already know that.  So do we.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function copyAppointments() {
  const sourceCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("exampleSource@group.calendar.google.com");
  const targetCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("targetExample@group.calendar.google.com");
  const dt=new Date();
  const starttime  = new Date(dt.getFullYear()-1,dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate(),0,0,0,0);//one year ago
  const endtime = new Date(dt.getFullYear()+1,dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate(),0,0,0,0);//next year
  const events = sourceCalendar.getEvents(starttime,endtime);
  events.forEach(e =>{
    targetCalendar.createEvent(e.getTitle(),starttime,endtime);
  });
}
```

Sorry I guess it should have been done like this:

```
function copyAppointments() {
  const sourceCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("exampleSource@group.calendar.google.com");
  const targetCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("targetExample@group.calendar.google.com");
  const dt=new Date();
  const starttime  = new Date(dt.getFullYear()-1,dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate(),0,0,0,0);//one year ago
  const endtime = new Date(dt.getFullYear()+1,dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate(),0,0,0,0);//next year
  const events = sourceCalendar.getEvents(starttime,endtime);
  events.forEach(e =>{
    targetCalendar.createEvent(e.getTitle(),e.getStartTime(),e.getEndTime());
  });
}
```

I just ran this simple test by exporting the event title,start time, and end Time to my spreadsheet and I received dates.

```
function copyAppointments() {
  const sourceCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("calid");
  const ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const tsh= ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const dt=new Date();
  const starttime  = new Date(dt.getFullYear()-1,dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate(),0,0,0,0);//one year ago
  const endtime = new Date(dt.getFullYear()+1,dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate(),0,0,0,0);//next year
  const events = sourceCalendar.getEvents(starttime,endtime);
  let oA=[];
  events.forEach(e =>{
     oA.push([e.getTitle(),e.getStartTime(),e.getEndTime()])
  });
  tsh.getRange(1,1,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues(oA);
}
```

Comment: Returns "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEvents' of null" in `const events = sourceCalendar.getEvents(starttime,endtime);`. I like how you defined the start- and endtimes, thank you.

Comment: Then sourceCalendar is not defined so perhaps there is something wrong with your id

Comment: I just noticed an error in the code.  I used event.forEach() rather than events.forEach() so that may have been the problem.

Comment: You were correct, the s was the problem. Now then, this line `targetCalendar.createEvent(e.getTitle(),starttime,endtime);` creates an event spanning about two years, per `const starttime  = new Date(dt.getFullYear()-1,dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate(),0,0,0,0);//one year ago const endtime = new Date(dt.getFullYear()+1,dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate(),0,0,0,0);//next year`.
Changing the last line to `    targetCalendar.createEvent(e.getTitle(),e.getStartTime(),e.getEndTime());` doesn't work.

Comment: Copied it from here: `events.forEach(e =>{ targetCalendar.createEvent(e.getTitle(),starttime,endtime);`, the eighth and ninth line of your code. Removing it from getStartTime and after is no better.

Comment: I think it should it returns a Date according to the documentation

Comment: According to my test getStartTime() and getEndTime() return dates.  I don't know what to tell you.  Make sure that you add the () because the new editor doesn't put them on for you.

Comment: Yes, with only `e.getStartTime(),e.getEndTime()` it does appear to work. I guess I wanted too much with also colour and stuff. Thank you.